# how to remove white border around the div

Tags: css, html

I am trying to develop a web site from scratch. Here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body >
<div id="top" style="height:200px;background-color:green">
</div>
<div id="middle" style="height:800px;background-color:white">
</div>
<div id="footer" style="height:200px;background-color:green">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Problem is that there is a white space around above div tags. I can remove white space using `margin: -10px;` property. But I don't like to handle it that way. Is there way to handle this in decent way in css?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```html
<body style="margin: 0;">
```

Answer (score 9):

Set the margin for the body to 0;

```
<body style = "margin:0">
```

Comment: OOPS! Sorry. Didn't see the answer above. Due to my slower internet connection, I got some delay in posting the answer.

Comment: Putting spaces around the `=`s of attributes is against the XML standard.