# How to get rid of white frame around image

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html/css and I'm trying to cover the top half of my website completely with this image. However, a white frame surrounds the image and for the life of me I can't seem to get rid of it.
Here's a photo of what it looks like:

[Image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig4oN.jpg)

HTML:

```
<body>
 <div id="my_header"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#my_header {
  background: url(pic1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 450px;
  border-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This isn't coming from the image, but rather the `body` and `html` tags. Add `html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0 }` to your CSS

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540102/how-to-remove-white-border-around-the-div or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903098/width-100-with-white-borders-around-it-why

Answer (score 0):

Check any styling on the body tag.
To remove padding and margin on body use the following

```
  body { padding: 0; margin: 0 }
```

Comment: only need to add `margin: 0`. Padding has nothing to do with it.